# How to put large number of posts at wordpress?

Tags: bulk-import

Is it possible to make a big file, say, a csv, or json file. Then "Import" the file to wordpress?

Also I want to be able to schedule the posts.

How would I do so?

Currently I am using vb.net to simply work with wordpress normal interface and post one by one.

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on from where you will be importing the articles. [You can check the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content) to see what existing solutions exist. If you are using custom CMS you can use [`[X]HTML`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Importing_from_.5BX.5DHTML) guide:

```
<item>
 <pubDate>Wed, 30 Jan 2009 12:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
 <category>Kites</category>
 <category>Taiwan</category>
 <title>Fun times</title>
 <content:encoded><p>What great times we had...</p><p>And then Bob...</p></content:encoded>
</item>
<item>...
```